# Javascript: Array does not work when it is a little long

Tags: javascript, arrays, replace

I want to replace Chinese characters to unicode and the unicode to *pinyin* (pronunciations of those characters) so that I can make Hansi (Persianized pronunciations). I do this using arrays. I don't have any problem with this:

```
 // here i got the chinese character and replaced it with unicode      
     var chini =  document.getElementById("ch1").value.charCodeAt(0);       
     var chiniuni= chini.toString(16);   


var mapUni1 = { 
"3007":"ling2", "4e00":"yi1", "4e01":"ding1", "4e02":"kao3", "4e03":"qi1", "4e04":"shang4---shang3", "4e05":"xia4", "4e06":"---", "4e07":"wan4---mo4", "4e08":"zhang4", "4e09":"san1", "4e0a":"shang4---shang3", "4e0b":"xia4", "4e0c":"ji1", "4e0d":"bu4", "4e0e":"yu3---yu4", "4e0f":"mian3", "4e10":"gai4","4e11":"chou3", "4e12":"chou3", "4e13":"zhuan1", "4e14":"qie3---ju1", "4e15":"pi1", "4e16":"shi4", "4e17":"shi4", "4e18":"qiu1", "4e19":"bing3", "4e1a":"ye4", "4e1b":"cong2", "4e1c":"dong1", 
        };

    var roo = new RegExp(Object.keys(mapUni1).join("|"),"gi");
    pinyin = chiniuni.toLowerCase().replace(roo, function(matched){
      return mapUni1[matched];
    });

   document.getElementById("bbb").innerHTML = pinyin
```

*check it here*: https://jsfiddle.net/6j7k5dqw/

But since there are a lot of Chinese characters (21000 in my work), the array must be a little long, and I read that it can be much much longer. But in my case, when I put a little more in the array, the code does not work at all:

```
         var chini =  document.getElementById("ch1").value.charCodeAt(0);       
         var chiniuni= chini.toString(16);   


    var mapUni1 = { 
        "3007":"ling2", "4e00":"yi1", "4e01":"ding1", "4e02":"kao3", "4e03":"qi1", "4e04":"shang4---shang3", "4e05":"xia4", "4e06":"---", "4e07":"wan4---mo4", "4e08":"zhang4", "4e09":"san1", "4e0a":"shang4---shang3", "4e0b":"xia4", "4e0c":"ji1", "4e0d":"bu4", "4e0e":"yu3---yu4", "4e0f":"mian3", "4e10":"gai4","4e11":"chou3", "4e12":"chou3", "4e13":"zhuan1", "4e14":"qie3---ju1", "4e15":"pi1", "4e16":"shi4", "4e17":"shi4", "4e18":"qiu1", "4e19":"bing3", "4e1a":"ye4", "4e1b":"cong2", "4e1c":"dong1", "4e1d":"si1", "4e1e":"cheng2", "4e1f":"diu1", "4e20":"qiu1", "4e21":"liang3", "4e22":"diu1", "4e23":"you3", "4e24":"liang3", "4e25":"yan2", "4e26":"bing4", "4e27":"sang1---sang4", "4e28":"shu4", "4e29":"jiu1", "4e2a":"ge4", "4e2b":"ya1", "4e2c":"qiang2---pan2", "4e2d":"zhong1---zhong4", "4e2e":"ji3", "4e2f":"jie4", "4e30":"feng1", "4e31":"guan4", "4e32":"chuan4", "4e33":"chan3", "4e34":"lin2", "4e35":"zhuo1", "4e36":"zhu3", "4e37":"---", "4e38":"wan2",
"4e39":"dan1", "4e3a":"wei4---wei2", "4e3b":"zhu3", "4e3c":"jing3---dan3", "4e3d":"li4---li2", "4e3e":"ju3", "4e3f":"pie3", "4e40":"fu2", "4e41":"yi2", "4e42":"yi4---ai4", "4e43":"nai3", "4e44":"---", "4e45":"jiu3", "4e46":"jiu3", "4e47":"tuo1", "4e48":"yao1---mo2", "4e49":"yi4", "4e4a":"---", "4e4b":"zhi1", "4e4c":"wu1---wu4", "4e4d":"zha4", "4e4e":"hu1", "4e4f":"fa2", "4e50":"le4---yue4", "4e51":"zhong4", "4e52":"ping1", "4e53":"pang1", "4e54":"qiao2", "4e55":"hu3---hu4", "4e56":"guai1", "4e57":"cheng2---sheng4", "4e58":"cheng2---sheng4", "4e59":"yi3", "4e5a":"yin3", "4e5b":"---", "4e5c":"mie1---nie4", "4e5d":"jiu3", "4e5e":"qi3", "4e5f":"ye3", "4e60":"xi2", "4e61":"xiang1", "4e62":"gai4", "4e63":"diu1", "4e64":"---", "4e65":"---", "4e66":"shu1", "4e67":"---", "4e68":"shi3", "4e69":"ji1", "4e6a":"nang1", "4e6b":"jia1", "4e6c":"---", "4e6d":"shi2", "4e6e":"---", "4e6f":"---", "4e70":"mai3", "4e71":"luan4", "4e72":"---", "4e73":"ru3", "4e74":"xi3", "4e75":"yan3", "4e76":"fu3", "4e77":"sha1", "4e78":"na3", "4e79":"gan1---qian2", "4e7a":"---", "4e7b":"---", "4e7c":"---", "4e7d":"---", "4e7e":"gan1---qian2", "4e7f":"zhi4", "4e80":"gui1---jun1---qiu1", "4e81":"gan1", "4e82":"luan4", "4e83":"lin3", "4e84":"yi4", "4e85":"jue2", "4e86":"liao3---le5", "4e87":"---", "4e88":"yu2---yu3", "4e89":"zheng1", "4e8a":"shi4", "4e8b":"shi4", "4e8c":"er4", "4e8d":"chu4", "4e8e":"yu2", "4e8f":"kui1", "4e90":"yu2", "4e91":"yun2", "4e92":"hu4", "4e93":"qi2", "4e94":"wu3", "4e95":"jing3", "4e96":"si4",
"4e97":"sui4", "4e98":"gen4", "4e99":"gen4---geng4", "4e9a":"ya4", "4e9b":"xie1", "4e9c":"ya4", "4e9d":"qi2", "4e9e":"ya4---ya3", "4e9f":"ji2---qi4", "4ea0":"tou2", "4ea1":"wang2---wu2", "4ea2":"kang4", "4ea3":"ta4", "4ea4":"jiao1", "4ea5":"hai4", "4ea6":"yi4", "4ea7":"chan3", "4ea8":"heng1", "4ea9":"mu3", "4eaa":"---", "4eab":"xiang3", "4eac":"jing1", "4ead":"ting2", "4eae":"liang4", "4eaf":"heng1", "4eb0":"jing1", "4eb1":"ye4", "4eb2":"qin1---qing4", "4eb3":"bo4", "4eb4":"you4", "4eb5":"xie4", "4eb6":"dan3", "4eb7":"lian2", "4eb8":"duo3", "4eb9":"wei3---wei4", "4eba":"ren2", "4ebb":"ren2", "4ebc":"ji2", "4ebd":"---", "4ebe":"wang2", "4ebf":"yi4", "4ec0":"shi2---shen2", "4ec1":"ren2", "4ec2":"le4", "4ec3":"ding1", "4ec4":"ze4", "4ec5":"jin3---jin4", "4ec6":"pu1---pu2", "4ec7":"chou2---qiu2", "4ec8":"ba1", "4ec9":"zhang3", "4eca":"jin1", "4ecb":"jie4", "4ecc":"bing1", "4ecd":"reng2", "4ece":"cong2", "4ecf":"fo2---fu2", "4ed0":"san3", "4ed1":"lun2", "4ed2":"---", "4ed3":"cang1", "4ed4":"zi3", "4ed5":"shi4", "4ed6":"ta1", "4ed7":"zhang4", "4ed8":"fu4", "4ed9":"xian1", "4eda":"xian1", "4edb":"cha4", "4edc":"hong2", "4edd":"tong2", "4ede":"ren4", "4edf":"qian1", "4ee0":"gan3", "4ee1":"yi4---ge1", "4ee2":"di2", "4ee3":"dai4", "4ee4":"ling4---ling2---ling3", "4ee5":"yi3", "4ee6":"chao4", "4ee7":"chang2", "4ee8":"sa1", "4ee9":"shang4", "4eea":"yi2", "4eeb":"mu4",
"4eec":"men5---men2", "4eed":"ren4", "4eee":"jia3---jia4", "4eef":"chao4", "4ef0":"yang3", "4ef1":"qian2", "4ef2":"zhong4", "4ef3":"pi3", "4ef4":"wan4", "4ef5":"wu3", "4ef6":"jian4", "4ef7":"jia4", "4ef8":"yao3", "4ef9":"feng1", "4efa":"cang1", "4efb":"ren4---ren2", "4efc":"wang2", "4efd":"fen4", "4efe":"di1", "4eff":"fang3", "4f00":"zhong1", "4f01":"qi3---qi4", "4f02":"pei4", "4f03":"yu2", "4f04":"diao4", "4f05":"dun4", "4f06":"wen4", "4f07":"yi4", "4f08":"xin3", "4f09":"kang4", "4f0a":"yi1", "4f0b":"ji2", "4f0c":"ai4", "4f0d":"wu3", "4f0e":"ji4", "4f0f":"fu2", "4f10":"fa2---fa1", "4f11":"xiu1", "4f12":"jin4", "4f13":"bei1", "4f14":"chen2", "4f15":"fu1", "4f16":"tang3", "4f17":"zhong4", "4f18":"you1", "4f19":"huo3", "4f1a":"hui4---kuai4", "4f1b":"yu3", "4f1c":"cui4---zu2", "4f1d":"yun2", "4f1e":"san3", "4f1f":"wei3", "4f20":"zhuan4", "4f21":"che1", "4f22":"ya2", "4f23":"xian4", "4f24":"shang1", "4f25":"chang1", "4f26":"lun2", "4f27":"cang1---chen5", "4f28":"xun4", "4f29":"xin4", "4f2a":"wei3", "4f2b":"zhu4", "4f2c":"chi3", "4f2d":"xuan2", "4f2e":"nao2---nu3", "4f2f":"bo2---bai3", "4f30":"gu1---gu4", "4f31":"ni3", "4f32":"ni4", "4f33":"xie4", "4f34":"ban4", "4f35":"xu4", "4f36":"ling2", "4f37":"zhou4", "4f38":"shen1", "4f39":"qu1", "4f3a":"si4---ci4", "4f3b":"beng1", "4f3c":"si4---shi4", "4f3d":"jia1---qie2", "4f3e":"pi1", "4f3f":"yi4", "4f40":"si4---shi4", "4f41":"ai3", "4f42":"zheng1---zheng4", "4f43":"dian4---tian2", "4f44":"han2", "4f45":"mai4", "4f46":"dan4", "4f47":"zhu4", "4f48":"bu4", "4f49":"qu1", "4f4a":"bi3", "4f4b":"shao4", "4f4c":"ci3", "4f4d":"wei4", "4f4e":"di1", "4f4f":"zhu4", "4f50":"zuo3",
"4f51":"you4", "4f52":"yang1", "4f53":"ti3", "4f54":"zhan4", "4f55":"he2---he4", "4f56":"bi4", "4f57":"tuo2", "4f58":"she2", "4f59":"yu2---tu2", "4f5a":"yi4---die2", "4f5b":"fo2---fu2", "4f5c":"zuo1", "4f5d":"kou4", "4f5e":"ning4", "4f5f":"tong2", "4f60":"ni3", "4f61":"xuan1---san3", "4f62":"ju4", "4f63":"yong4---yong1", "4f64":"wa3", "4f65":"qian1", "4f66":"---", "4f67":"ka3", "4f68":"---", "4f69":"pei4", "4f6a":"huai2", "4f6b":"he4", "4f6c":"lao3", "4f6d":"xiang2", "4f6e":"ge2", "4f6f":"yang2", "4f70":"bai3", "4f71":"fa3", "4f72":"ming2", "4f73":"jia1", "4f74":"er4---nai4", "4f75":"bing4", "4f76":"ji2", "4f77":"heng2", "4f78":"huo2", "4f79":"gui3", "4f7a":"quan2", "4f7b":"tiao1---tiao2", "4f7c":"jiao3---jia3", "4f7d":"ci4", "4f7e":"yi4", "4f7f":"shi3", "4f80":"xing2", "4f81":"shen1", "4f82":"tuo1", "4f83":"kan3", "4f84":"zhi2", "4f85":"gai1---kai1", "4f86":"lai2", "4f87":"yi2", "4f88":"chi3", "4f89":"kua1---kua3", "4f8a":"guang1", "4f8b":"li4", "4f8c":"yin1", "4f8d":"shi4", "4f8e":"mi3", "4f8f":"zhu1", "4f90":"xu4", "4f91":"you4", "4f92":"an1", "4f93":"lu4", "4f94":"mou2", "4f95":"er2", "4f96":"lun2", "4f97":"dong4", "4f98":"cha4", "4f99":"chi4", "4f9a":"xun4", "4f9b":"gong1---gong4", "4f9c":"zhou1", "4f9d":"yi1", "4f9e":"ru3", "4f9f":"jian4", "4fa0":"xia2", "4fa1":"jia4---jie4", "4fa2":"zai4", "4fa3":"lu":"3", "4fa4":"---", "4fa5":"jiao3---yao2", "4fa6":"zhen1", "4fa7":"ce4", "4fa8":"qiao2", "4fa9":"kuai4", "4faa":"chai2", "4fab":"ning4", "4fac":"nong2", "4fad":"jin3---jin4", "4fae":"wu3", "4faf":"hou2---hou4", "4fb0":"jiong3", "4fb1":"cheng3", "4fb2":"zhen4", "4fb3":"cuo4", "4fb4":"chou3", "4fb5":"qin1", "4fb6":"lu":"3", "4fb7":"ju2", "4fb8":"shu4", "4fb9":"ting3", "4fba":"shen4", "4fbb":"tuo1", "4fbc":"bo2", "4fbd":"nan2", "4fbe":"hao1", "4fbf":"bian4---pian2", "4fc0":"tui3", "4fc1":"yu3", "4fc2":"xi4", "4fc3":"cu4", "4fc4":"e2---e4", "4fc5":"qiu2", "4fc6":"xu2", "4fc7":"kuang3", "4fc8":"ku4", "4fc9":"wu2", "4fca":"jun4", "4fcb":"yi4", "4fcc":"fu3", "4fcd":"lang2", "4fce":"zu3", "4fcf":"qiao4", "4fd0":"li4", "4fd1":"yong3", "4fd2":"hun4", "4fd3":"jing4", "4fd4":"xian4", "4fd5":"san4", "4fd6":"pai3", "4fd7":"su2", "4fd8":"fu2", "4fd9":"xi1", "4fda":"li3", "4fdb":"mian3", "4fdc":"ping1---ping2", "4fdd":"bao3", "4fde":"yu2", "4fdf":"si4---qi2", "4fe0":"xia2", "4fe1":"xin4---shen1", "4fe2":"xiu1", "4fe3":"yu3", "4fe4":"ti4", "4fe5":"che1", "4fe6":"chou2", "4fe7":"---", "4fe8":"yan3", "4fe9":"lia3---liang3", "4fea":"li4", "4feb":"lai2", "4fec":"si1", "4fed":"jian3", 
"4fee":"xiu1", "4fef":"fu3", "4ff0":"he2", "4ff1":"ju4---ju1", "4ff2":"xiao4", "4ff3":"pai2", "4ff4":"jian4", "4ff5":"biao3", "4ff6":"chu4", "4ff7":"fei4", "4ff8":"feng4", "4ff9":"ya4", "4ffa":"an3", "4ffb":"bei4", "4ffc":"yu4---zhou1", "4ffd":"xin1", "4ffe":"bi3", "4fff":"chi2", "5000":"chang1", "5001":"zhi1", "5002":"bing4", "5003":"zan2", "5004":"yao2", "5005":"cui4", "5006":"lia3---liang3", "5007":"wan3", "5008":"lai2", "5009":"cang1", "500a":"zong3", "500b":"ge4", "500c":"guan1", "500d":"bei4", "500e":"tian1", "500f":"shu1", "5010":"shu1", "5011":"men5---men2", "5012":"dao3---dao4", "5013":"tan2", "5014":"jue2---jue4", "5015":"chui2", "5016":"xing4", "5017":"peng2", "5018":"tang3---chang2", "5019":"hou4", "501a":"yi3", "501b":"qi1", "501c":"ti4", "501d":"gan4", "501e":"jing4---liang4", "501f":"jie4", "5020":"xu1", "5021":"chang4---chang1", "5022":"jie2", "5023":"fang3", "5024":"zhi2", "5025":"kong1---kong3", "5026":"juan4", "5027":"zong1", "5028":"ju4", "5029":"qian4", "502a":"ni2", "502b":"lun2", "502c":"zhuo1---zhuo2", "502d":"wo1", "502e":"luo3", "502f":"song1", "5030":"leng2", "5031":"hun4", "5032":"dong1", "5033":"zi4", "5034":"ben4", "5035":"wu3", "5036":"ju4---ju1", "5037":"nai4", "5038":"cai3", "5039":"jian3", "503a":"zhai4", "503b":"ye1", "503c":"zhi2", "503d":"sha4", "503e":"qing1", "503f":"---", "5040":"ying1", "5041":"cheng1---cheng4", "5042":"qian2", "5043":"yan3", "5044":"nuan4", "5045":"zhong4", "5046":"chun3", "5047":"jia3---jia4", "5048":"jie2---ji4", "5049":"wei3", "504a":"yu3", "504b":"bing4", "504c":"ruo4", "504d":"ti2", "504e":"wei1", "504f":"pian1", "5050":"yan4", "5051":"feng1", "5052":"tang3", "5053":"wo4", "5054":"e4", "5055":"xie2", "5056":"che3", "5057":"sheng3", "5058":"kan3", "5059":"di4", "505a":"zuo4", "505b":"cha1", "505c":"ting2", "505d":"bei1", "505e":"ye4", "505f":"huang2", "5060":"yao3", "5061":"zhan4", "5062":"qiu1", "5063":"yan1",
"5064":"you2", "5065":"jian4", "5066":"xu3", "5067":"zha1", "5068":"chai1", "5069":"fu4", "506a":"bi1", "506b":"zhi4", "506c":"zong3", "506d":"mian3", "506e":"ji2", "506f":"yi3", "5070":"xie4", "5071":"xun2", "5072":"si1", "5073":"duan1", "5074":"ce4", "5075":"zhen1", "5076":"ou3", "5077":"tou1", "5078":"tou1", "5079":"bei4", "507a":"za2---zan2", "507b":"lu":"3---lou2", "507c":"jie2", "507d":"wei4", "507e":"fen4", "507f":"chang2", "5080":"gui1---kui3", "5081":"sou3", "5082":"chi3", "5083":"su4", "5084":"xia1", "5085":"fu4", "5086":"yuan4", "5087":"rong3", "5088":"li4", "5089":"ru4", "508a":"yun3", "508b":"gou4", "508c":"ma4", "508d":"bang4---bang1", "508e":"dian1", "508f":"tang2", "5090":"hao1", "5091":"jie2", "5092":"xi1", "5093":"shan1", "5094":"qian4", "5095":"jue2", "5096":"cang1---chen5", "5097":"chu4", "5098":"san3", "5099":"bei4", "509a":"xiao4", "509b":"yong2", "509c":"yao2", "509d":"ta4", "509e":"suo1", "509f":"wang1", "50a0":"fa2", "50a1":"bing4---bing1", "50a2":"jia1", "50a3":"tai4", "50a4":"zai4", "50a5":"tang3", "50a6":"---", "50a7":"bin1", "50a8":"chu3", "50a9":"nuo2", "50aa":"zan1", "50ab":"lei3", "50ac":"cui1", "50ad":"yong1---yong4", "50ae":"zao1", "50af":"zong3", "50b0":"peng2", "50b1":"song3", "50b2":"ao4", "50b3":"chuan2---zhuan4", "50b4":"yu3", "50b5":"zhai4", "50b6":"zu2", "50b7":"shang1", "50b8":"qiang3", "50b9":"qiang1", "50ba":"chi4", "50bb":"sha3", "50bc":"han4", "50bd":"zhang1", "50be":"qing1", "50bf":"yan4", "50c0":"di4", "50c1":"xi1", "50c2":"lu":"3---lou2", "50c3":"bei4", "50c4":"piao1", "50c5":"jin3---jin4", "50c6":"lian3", "50c7":"lu4", "50c8":"man4", "50c9":"qian1", "50ca":"xian1", "50cb":"qiu2", "50cc":"ying2", "50cd":"dong4", "50ce":"zhuan4", "50cf":"xiang4", "50d0":"shan3", "50d1":"qiao2", "50d2":"jiong3", "50d3":"tui2", "50d4":"zun3", "50d5":"pu2---pu1", "50d6":"xi1", "50d7":"lao4", "50d8":"chang3", "50d9":"guang1", "50da":"liao2", "50db":"qi1", "50dc":"deng4", "50dd":"chan2", "50de":"wei3", "50df":"zhang3", "50e0":"fan1", "50e1":"hui4", "50e2":"chuan3", "50e3":"tie3", "50e4":"dan4", "50e5":"jiao3---yao2", "50e6":"jiu4", "50e7":"seng1", "50e8":"fen4", "50e9":"xian4", "50ea":"jue2", "50eb":"e4", "50ec":"jiao1", "50ed":"jian4", "50ee":"tong2", "50ef":"lin2", "50f0":"bo2---fu2", "50f1":"gu4", "50f2":"xian1", "50f3":"su4", "50f4":"xian4", "50f5":"jiang1", "50f6":"min3", "50f7":"ye4", "50f8":"jin4", "50f9":"jia4", "50fa":"qiao4", "50fb":"pi4", "50fc":"feng1", "50fd":"zhou4", "50fe":"ai4", "50ff":"sai4", "5100":"yi2", "5101":"jun4---juan4", "5102":"nong2", "5103":"shan4", "5104":"yi4", "5105":"dang1", "5106":"jing3", "5107":"xuan1", "5108":"kuai4", "5109":"jian3", "510a":"chu4", "510b":"dan1", "510c":"jiao3", "510d":"sha3", "510e":"zai4---zai3", "510f":"---", "5110":"bin4---bin1", "5111":"an4", "5112":"ru2", "5113":"tai2", "5114":"chou2", "5115":"chai2", "5116":"lan2", "5117":"ni3", "5118":"jin3", "5119":"qian1", "511a":"meng2", "511b":"wu3", "511c":"neng2", "511d":"qiong2", "511e":"ni3", 
    };

        var roo = new RegExp(Object.keys(mapUni1).join("|"),"gi");
        pinyin = chiniuni.toLowerCase().replace(roo, function(matched){
          return mapUni1[matched];
        });

       document.getElementById("bbb").innerHTML = pinyin
```

*See it here*: https://jsfiddle.net/drm65da5/

P.S: I know about difficulties of arrays but I have my own reasons to do this only in this way, so please do not suggest to use different methods. Thanks.

Comment: What doesn't work "at all"? Does it give the wrong output? If so, what does it give vs what you expected? Does it not output all?

Comment: You’ve got a syntax error here: `"4fa3":"lu":"3"`. This isn’t an array, it’s an object. Use the [browser console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read the errors. Use [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) to find problems with your code immediately. You already know, that adding a specific portion of code introduces an error, so you know the error must be somewhere in the added code. Continue that approach of removing new code and adding old code and you’ll find the error. Also check the syntax highlighting.

Comment: @xufox Oh, yes, you're right, I didn't think the problem would be of this kind. Silly me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *long* object has an extra colon at:

```
 "507b":"lu":"3---lou2", 
            ^
```

And probably more. I can't provide a solution because it's up to you which of the strings above is the key and its value. Generally, always look at the console, first. It's the initial place for debugging.